# How to highlight android listview first item after load items to listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

1.This is my listview

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_FromTable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

2.in onCreate of main activity i load item and set adapter to listview

```
lv_FromTable = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_FromTable);
FromTableAdapter = new ManageTableAdapter(context, FromTableList);
lv_FromTable.setAdapter(FromTableAdapter);
FromTableAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

3.i want to highlight on first item same click on listview item

4.i have already tried below code

`lv_FromTable.performItemClick(lv_FromTable.getAdapter().getView(0, null, null), 0, lv_FromTable.getAdapter().getItemId(0));`

it's raise onitemclick event but not highlight on first item.

5. How to highlight android listview first item after load items to listview?

Comment: try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5926002/410487)

Comment: @AlvinThen i try that but nothing change. thank

Comment: `ManageTableAdapter` is custom adapter means you can set background within adapter itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FromTableAdapter.setSelectedPosition(0); 
FromTableAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Have getter and setter in adapter with selected position and use the variable and highlight the selected row in getView of adapter.

**or**

You're performing click right. 
In `onItemClick`, `view.setSelected(true);` but your drawable xml should have something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/pressed_color"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/default_color" />
</selector>
```

**or**

```
lv_FromTable.setItemChecked(0,true);
```

**Edit** : Don't forget, without the `listSelector` above wont work

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_background" />
```

Comment: adapter is no setSelectedPosition() method