# Detect when BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() finished

Tags: android, baseadapter

I want to know when `BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` finish and then do sonething. My code:

```
BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  
mScroller.startScroll(oldX, 0, dx, 0);
```

`mScroller` scrolls before  `notifyDataSetChanged()` finishes. I want `mScroller` to scroll to `oldX` after `notifyDataSetChanged()` finishes.

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: watch [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942582/smoothscrolltoposition-after-notifydatasetchanged-not-working-in-android) question.
possible duplicate.

Comment: may be https://stackoverflow.com/a/20997828/5255006 will help you

Answer (score 12):

Instead of extending, `BaseAdapter` supports registering a `DataSetObserver` where you can listen for the `onChanged` event.

The `notifyDataSetChanged` method will cause this event to fire.

```
adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        // ...
    }
});

...

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Unfortunately the method `onChanged()` is called mutiple times and not only when the view layout has finished.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact problem, try this out it worked perfectly for me.
You are Overriding the method notifyDataSetChanged(). You do this in your Adapter class. Just copy the code i posted and replace the line where I setSelection() with what ever you need done.

```
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged()
{
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();

    parentGlobal.setSelection(this.getCount() - 1);  //This is how we start Activity fully scrolled to bottom
}
```

With that said, in case you are wondering, "parentGlobal" is the ListView that I set the Adapter to in my Activity. In the constructor of the Adapter, I passed in the ListView and then made it "global". I apologize if "global" isn't a Java term, I come from a C++ world.

//Goes in Activity:

```
lv_main = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_conversation);
    adapter_main = new Adapter_Conversation(ConversationActivity.this, R.layout.layout_list_conversation,
            list_main_UI, lv_main, main_list_item_margin_px);
    lv_main.setAdapter(adapter_main);
```

//Goes in Adapter

```
public Adapter_Conversation(AppCompatActivity activity, @LayoutRes int resource,
                            ArrayList<Adapter_GetSet_Conversation> list_conversation, ListView lv_main,
                            int item_margin_px)
```

Comment: nowadays: 'notifyDataSetChanged()' cannot override 'notifyDataSetChanged()' in 'androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter'; overridden method is final

Answer (score 1):

See the following (more modern) implementation with a kotlin extension function:

```
fun <VH : ViewHolder> RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>.notifyDataSetChanged(
    completion: () -> Unit
) {
    val adapter = this
    val observer = object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        override fun onChanged() {
            super.onChanged()
            adapter.unregisterAdapterDataObserver(this)
            completion.invoke()
        }
    }
    registerAdapterDataObserver(observer)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem and I end up doing this-

```
 BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
              public void run() {
                 mScroller.startScroll(oldX, 0, dx, 0);
                //write scroll code here
               }
       },50);  //scroll after 50ms
```

Comment: I used to do that too, problem I had was that it's timing driven and not event driven so you have to guess the right timing and then it could easily change depending on which device is running it since newer devices can be much faster than some of the older devices.

Comment: yes there can be alot of hacks tricks to do , also below 1 second is not much noticeable time for animating.